# Old spirits take over people's bodies, protagonist's wife is a victim

Tags: story-identification, books

This is a book I read about 16 years ago, and I don't think it was particularly old then.

What I recall of the book is that for the most part it was set in the woods of the American Pacific northwest. The protagonist notices that his (ex?) wife is behaving differently. Over the course of the book we discover her body has been taken over by an old spirit, possibly as a way of achieving immortality. There is a whole group of them that is now very powerful he is unlikely to defeat them. (I think he fails in the end.)

The author's initial (maybe both initials) was "M," Michael something possibly.

Comment: Some of this sounds similar to the series Intruders- maybe the show was based on the book? If so it probably has the same title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're a couple of years off on the date, it might be [*The Intruders*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?907909) by "Michael Marshall," a pen name of Michael Marshall Smith.  It was published in 2007 (April in the U.K., August in the U.S.), 15 years ago being fairly close to 16.  The author's name "Michael Marshall," also matches your recollection of the name.

The book is set in Seattle, WA and in Oregon, which matches the Pacific northwest.

The blurb (copied from [Fantastic Fiction](https://www.fantasticfiction.com/m/michael-marshall/intruders.htm)):

> Jack Whalen was an LAPD patrol cop for twelve years. He left in difficult circumstances and now he's not really sure what he is. **He's not too sure about his wife**, either — when she goes missing on a routine business trip to Seattle, Jack heads up there to find her: only to discover she's not really missing after all. Over the coming days it becomes increasingly clear that **something has changed, however** — and is still changing. Jack is meanwhile contacted by a childhood acquaintance, Gary Fisher. Fisher's a lawyer now, and wants help in solving an odd little mystery concerning a businessman's will. The further Jack digs, the bigger the mystery seems to be — and the stranger Fisher becomes. And in Oregon, a ten-year-old girl goes missing. It gradually becomes clear that she's at least partly in control of the situation, however — and also that she's very far from defenceless. Searching for answers in the dark secrets of a past that still haunts him, Jack discovers that the truth has roots deeper and darker than he ever feared.

A [review on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/RIF6YQOERNDDD) mentions the Nine, a secret society that is behind the mystery.  A review on the [Goodreads page](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/128640.The_Intruders) mentions characters fighting for control of their minds:

> we see inside Madison's very confused 9 year old mind and it is heartbreaking to see how hard she fights to maintain control of her very young life, and shows that kid is a mega badass for how hard she fights back.

Synthesizing various snippets, it seems that reincarnation is possible, but mostly the reincarnated spirit doesn't take over.  The Nine, however, have a way to strengthen themselves so that they can fight the host's spirit and become the dominant personality in the people they reincarnate into.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have already ordered the book (having written what you wrote I am surprised at how accurate my memory was, maybe old age isn't having such am impact after all)